# Perspective Vision on Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, 3d, 2.5d

today I'm bringing a subject about Pseudo 3D and perspective.

I was checking the video [#1 Java Classical 3D Rendering Tutorial : Creating 3D World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am6iWLOHhEk) where he used a method for render pseudo-3D ceil and floor. I tried to find some tutorial or the name of the method that he used but I didn't find. I saw the algorithm but it is not clear to understand. I started to search about perspective graphics (vanishing points, horizon...) but the unique thing that I got was static drawing. I wanna apply an illusion moving putting the camera inside the plan and moving it. Under follow an example about the perspective floor and ceiling that I wanna make.

[image: Static Perspective Image]
[image: Static Perspective Image]

This is just an image, but my first question is: "I realy can make a movement of the camera in this ambient, like rotation and move x, and y axis?". I tried to make 2 vanishing point in a canvas, creating lines for each degree of 15º, and I got a perspective illusion, but i couldn't find a way to make the rotation, or the movement. In that video I saw the pixels creating 2 dimensions using just the colors green and blue, but I wanna make this using lines, to understand how it works.

[image]

There isn't a place that is teaching step by step how to make the perspective with movements. I didn't find. I checked the videos of 3D game maker in Java and the Markus Person creating the game called by "Prelude of the chambered" using the method of the video, but I didn't find an explanation for this king of rendering.

[image]

Lets supose I have to create a plan using a grid. how is the logic that I have to apply in the lines to create the movement? I realy wanna understand the logic to make this kind of pseudo-3D, without using frameworks or thing like that. Thanks for help me! I will wait for your answer.

I checked something about MODE 7 of SNES. This is a good way for make it I think. I have just to understand how it works, and how to make the rotation.

[image]

** Note: I don't what to use raycasting for it. Raycasting I'll use to create the walls.

Comment: I added answer with Vector approach using homogenuous coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. I did not resist and code it for fun so here some insights... Well there are 2 basic approaches for this. One is raster fake and second is Vector based. I will describe the latter as you can do much more with it.

**Vector approach**

This approach is not faking anything it really is **3D**. The rest depends on the rendering you want to use this for... For now I assume you can render **2D** lines. All the code chunks are in **C++**.

1. **Transformations**

   You need vector math to transform points between world and camera space and back again. In **3D** graphics are usually **4x4 homogenuous transform matrices** used for this and many programing **API**s support them natively. I will base my math on **OpenGL** matrix layout which determine the order of multiplication used. For more info I strongly recommend to read this:

   - [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

   As I use a lot from it. The linked answers there are also useful especially the **3D** graphics pipeline and Full pseudo inverse matrix. The Answer itself is basic knowledge needed for **3D** rendering in a nutshell (low level without the need for any lib apart of the rendering stuff).

   There are also libs for this like **GLM** so if you want you can use any linear algebra supporting **4x4** matrices and **4D** vectors instead of my code.

   So lets have two `4x4` matrices one (`camera`) representing our camera coordinate system and second (`icamera`) which is its inverse. Now if we want to transform between world and screen space we simply do this:

   ```
   P = camera*Q
   Q = icamera*P
   ```

   where `P(x,y,z,1)` is point in camera coordinate system and `Q(x,y,z,1)` is the same point in global world coordinate system.
2. **Perspective**

   This is done simply by dividing `P` by its `z` coordinate. That will scale objects around `(0,0)` so the more far object is the smaller will be. If we add some screen resolution and axis correction we can use this:

   ```
   void perspective(double *P) // apply perspective transform on P
       {
       // perspectve division
       P[0]*=znear/P[2];
       P[1]*=znear/P[2];
       // screen coordinate system
       P[0]=xs2+P[0];          // move (0,0) to screen center
       P[1]=ys2-P[1];          // axises: x=right, y=up
       }
   ```

   so point `0,0` is center of screen. The `xs2,ys2` is half of resolution of the screen and `znear` is focal length of the projection. So `XY` plane rectangle with screen resolution and center at `(0,0,znear)`  will cover the screen exactly.
3. **Rendering 3D line**

   We can use any primitives for rendering. I chose line as it is very simple and can achieve much. So what we want is to render **3D** line using **2D** line rendering **API** (of any kind). I am **VCL** based so I chose [**VCL/GDI** `Canvas`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214) which should be very similar to your `Canvas`.

   So as input we got two **3D** points in global world coordinate system. In order to render it with **2D** line we need to convert the **3D** position to **2D** screen space. That is done by `matrix*vector` multiplication.

   From that we obtain two **3D** points but in camera coordinate system. Now we need to clip the line by our view area (**Frustrum**). We can ignore `x,y` axises as **2D** line api usually does that for us anyway. So the only thing left is clip `z` axis. **Frustrum** in `z` axis is defined by `znear` and `zfar`. Where `zfar` is our max visibility distance from camera focal point. So if our line is fully before or after our `z-range` we ignore it and do not render. If it is inside we render it. If it crosses `znear` or `zfar` we cut the outside part off (by linear interpolation of the `x,y` coordinates).

   Now we just apply perspective on both points and render **2D** line using their `x,y` coordinates.

   My code for this looks  like this:

   ```
   void draw_line(TCanvas *can,double *pA,double *pB)  // draw 3D line
       {
       int i;
       double D[3],A[3],B[3],t;
       // transform to camera coordinate system
       matrix_mul_vector(A,icamera,pA);
       matrix_mul_vector(B,icamera,pB);
       // sort points so A.z<B.z
       if (A[2]>B[2]) for (i=0;i<3;i++) { D[i]=A[i]; A[i]=B[i]; B[i]=D[i]; }
       // D = B-A
       for (i=0;i<3;i++) D[i]=B[i]-A[i];
       // ignore out of Z view lines
       if (A[2]>zfar) return;
       if (B[2]<znear) return;
       // cut line to view if needed
       if (A[2]<znear)
           {
           t=(znear-A[2])/D[2];
           A[0]+=D[0]*t;
           A[1]+=D[1]*t;
           A[2]=znear;
           }
       if (B[2]>zfar)
           {
           t=(zfar-B[2])/D[2];
           B[0]+=D[0]*t;
           B[1]+=D[1]*t;
           B[2]=zfar;
           }
       // apply perspective
       perspective(A);
       perspective(B);
       // render
       can->MoveTo(A[0],A[1]);
       can->LineTo(B[0],B[1]);
       }
   ```
4. **Rendering `XZ` plane**

   We can visualize the ground and sky planes using our **3D** line as grid of squares. So we just create `for` loops rendering the `x`-axis aligned lines and `y`-axis aligned lines covering some square of some `size` around some origin  position `O`. The lines should be some `step` far between each other equal to grid cell size.

   The origin position `O` should be near our **frustrun** center. If it would be constant then we could walk out of the plane edges so it woul dnot cover the whole (half)screen. We can use our camera position and add `0.5*(zfar+znear)*camera_z_axis` to it. To maintain the illusion of movement we need to align the `O` to `step` size. We can exploit `floor`,`round` or integer cast for this.

   The resulting plane code looks like this:

   ```
   void draw_plane_xz(TCanvas *can,double y,double step) // draw 3D plane
       {
       int i;
       double A[3],B[3],t,size;
       double U[3]={1.0,0.0,0.0};  // U = X
       double V[3]={0.0,0.0,1.0};  // V = Z
       double O[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0};  // Origin
       // compute origin near view center but align to step
       i=0; O[i]=floor(camera[12+i]/step)*step;
       i=2; O[i]=floor(camera[12+i]/step)*step;
       O[1]=y;
       // set size so plane safely covers whole view
       t=xs2*zfar/znear;               size=t; // x that will convert to xs2 at zfar
       t=0.5*(zfar+znear); if (size<t) size=t; // half of depth range
       t+=step;                                // + one grid cell beacuse O is off up to 1 grid cell
       t*=sqrt(2);                             // diagonal so no matter how are we rotate in Yaw
       // U lines
       for (i=0;i<3;i++)
           {
           A[i]=O[i]+(size*U[i])-((step+size)*V[i]);
           B[i]=O[i]-(size*U[i])-((step+size)*V[i]);
           }
       for (t=-size;t<=size;t+=step)
           {
           for (i=0;i<3;i++)
               {
               A[i]+=step*V[i];
               B[i]+=step*V[i];
               }
           draw_line(can,A,B);
           }
       // V lines
       for (i=0;i<3;i++)
           {
           A[i]=O[i]-((step+size)*U[i])+(size*V[i]);
           B[i]=O[i]-((step+size)*U[i])-(size*V[i]);
           }
       for (t=-size;t<=size;t+=step)
           {
           for (i=0;i<3;i++)
               {
               A[i]+=step*U[i];
               B[i]+=step*U[i];
               }
           draw_line(can,A,B);
           }
       matrix_mul_vector(A,icamera,A);
       }
   ```

Now if I put all this together in small **VCL/GDI/Canvas** application I got this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h> // you can ignore these lines
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm" // up to here.
TMain *Main; // this is pointer to my VCL window (you do not need it)
//--- Here starts the important stuff: --------------------------------------
// perspective
double znear= 100.0;    // focal length for perspective
double zfar = 2100.0;   // visibility
// view
double xs2=0.0;         // screen half resolution
double ys2=0.0;
// camera
double yaw=0.0;         // euler yaw angle [rad]
double camera[16];      // camera direct transform matrix
double icamera[16];     // camera inverse transform matrix
// keyboard bools
bool _forw=false,_back=false,_right=false,_left=false;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void matrix_inv(double *a,double *b) // a[16] = Inverse(b[16])
    {
    double x,y,z;
    // transpose of rotation matrix
    a[ 0]=b[ 0];
    a[ 5]=b[ 5];
    a[10]=b[10];
    x=b[1]; a[1]=b[4]; a[4]=x;
    x=b[2]; a[2]=b[8]; a[8]=x;
    x=b[6]; a[6]=b[9]; a[9]=x;
    // copy projection part
    a[ 3]=b[ 3];
    a[ 7]=b[ 7];
    a[11]=b[11];
    a[15]=b[15];
    // convert origin: new_pos = - new_rotation_matrix * old_pos
    x=(a[ 0]*b[12])+(a[ 4]*b[13])+(a[ 8]*b[14]);
    y=(a[ 1]*b[12])+(a[ 5]*b[13])+(a[ 9]*b[14]);
    z=(a[ 2]*b[12])+(a[ 6]*b[13])+(a[10]*b[14]);
    a[12]=-x;
    a[13]=-y;
    a[14]=-z;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void  matrix_mul_vector(double *c,double *a,double *b) // c[3] = a[16]*b[3]
    {
    double q[3];
    q[0]=(a[ 0]*b[0])+(a[ 4]*b[1])+(a[ 8]*b[2])+(a[12]);
    q[1]=(a[ 1]*b[0])+(a[ 5]*b[1])+(a[ 9]*b[2])+(a[13]);
    q[2]=(a[ 2]*b[0])+(a[ 6]*b[1])+(a[10]*b[2])+(a[14]);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=q[i];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void compute_matrices() // recompute camera,icamera after camera position or yaw change
    {
    // bound angle
    while (yaw>2.0*M_PI) yaw-=2.0*M_PI;
    while (yaw<0.0     ) yaw+=2.0*M_PI;
    // X = right
    camera[ 0]= cos(yaw);
    camera[ 1]=     0.0 ;
    camera[ 2]= sin(yaw);
    // Y = up
    camera[ 4]=     0.0 ;
    camera[ 5]=     1.0 ;
    camera[ 6]=     0.0 ;
    // Z = forward
    camera[ 8]=-sin(yaw);
    camera[ 9]=     0.0 ;
    camera[10]= cos(yaw);
    // no projection
    camera[ 3]=     0.0 ;
    camera[ 7]=     0.0 ;
    camera[11]=     0.0 ;
    camera[15]=     1.0 ;
    // compute the inverse matrix
    matrix_inv(icamera,camera);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void perspective(double *P) // apply perspective transform
    {
    // perspectve division
    P[0]*=znear/P[2];
    P[1]*=znear/P[2];
    // screen coordinate system
    P[0]=xs2+P[0];          // move (0,0) to screen center
    P[1]=ys2-P[1];          // axises: x=right, y=up
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw_line(TCanvas *can,double *pA,double *pB)  // draw 3D line
    {
    int i;
    double D[3],A[3],B[3],t;
    // transform to camera coordinate system
    matrix_mul_vector(A,icamera,pA);
    matrix_mul_vector(B,icamera,pB);
    // sort points so A.z<B.z
    if (A[2]>B[2]) for (i=0;i<3;i++) { D[i]=A[i]; A[i]=B[i]; B[i]=D[i]; }
    // D = B-A
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) D[i]=B[i]-A[i];
    // ignore out of Z view lines
    if (A[2]>zfar) return;
    if (B[2]<znear) return;
    // cut line to view if needed
    if (A[2]<znear)
        {
        t=(znear-A[2])/D[2];
        A[0]+=D[0]*t;
        A[1]+=D[1]*t;
        A[2]=znear;
        }
    if (B[2]>zfar)
        {
        t=(zfar-B[2])/D[2];
        B[0]+=D[0]*t;
        B[1]+=D[1]*t;
        B[2]=zfar;
        }
    // apply perspective
    perspective(A);
    perspective(B);
    // render
    can->MoveTo(A[0],A[1]);
    can->LineTo(B[0],B[1]);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw_plane_xz(TCanvas *can,double y,double step) // draw 3D plane
    {
    int i;
    double A[3],B[3],t,size;
    double U[3]={1.0,0.0,0.0};  // U = X
    double V[3]={0.0,0.0,1.0};  // V = Z
    double O[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0};  // Origin
    // compute origin near view center but align to step
    i=0; O[i]=floor(camera[12+i]/step)*step;
    i=2; O[i]=floor(camera[12+i]/step)*step;
    O[1]=y;
    // set size so plane safely covers whole view
    t=xs2*zfar/znear;               size=t; // x that will convert to xs2 at zfar
    t=0.5*(zfar+znear); if (size<t) size=t; // half of depth range
    t+=step;                                // + one grid cell beacuse O is off up to 1 grid cell
    t*=sqrt(2);                             // diagonal so no matter how are we rotate in Yaw
    // U lines
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        A[i]=O[i]+(size*U[i])-((step+size)*V[i]);
        B[i]=O[i]-(size*U[i])-((step+size)*V[i]);
        }
    for (t=-size;t<=size;t+=step)
        {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
            A[i]+=step*V[i];
            B[i]+=step*V[i];
            }
        draw_line(can,A,B);
        }
    // V lines
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        A[i]=O[i]-((step+size)*U[i])+(size*V[i]);
        B[i]=O[i]-((step+size)*U[i])-(size*V[i]);
        }
    for (t=-size;t<=size;t+=step)
        {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
            A[i]+=step*U[i];
            B[i]+=step*U[i];
            }
        draw_line(can,A,B);
        }
    matrix_mul_vector(A,icamera,A);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw() // this is my main rendering routine
    {
    // clear buffer
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clWhite;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));
    // init/update variables
    double step= 50.0;                              // plane grid size
    ::xs2=Main->xs2;                                // update actual screen half resolution
    ::ys2=Main->ys2;
    // sky
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlue;
    draw_plane_xz(bmp->Canvas,+200.0,step);
    // terrain
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clGreen;
    draw_plane_xz(bmp->Canvas,-200.0,step);
    // render backbuffer
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    _redraw=false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner) // this is initialization
    {
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    pyx=NULL;
    _redraw=true;


    // camera start position
    camera[12]=0.0;
    camera[13]=0.0;
    camera[14]=0.0;
    compute_matrices();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender) // this is exit
    {
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender) // this is called on resize
    {
    xs=ClientWidth;  xs2=xs>>1;
    ys=ClientHeight; ys2=ys>>1;
    bmp->Width=xs;
    bmp->Height=ys;
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    pyx=new int*[ys];
    for (int y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y]=(int*) bmp->ScanLine[y];
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormPaint(TObject *Sender) // this is called on forced repaint
    {
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::tim_redrawTimer(TObject *Sender) // this is called periodically by my timer
    {
    double da=5.0*M_PI/180.0;   // turn speed
    double dl=15.0;             // movement speed
    bool _recompute=false;
    if (_left ) { _redraw=true; _recompute=true; yaw+=da; }
    if (_right) { _redraw=true; _recompute=true; yaw-=da; }
    if (_forw ) { _redraw=true; _recompute=true; for (int i=0;i<3;i++) camera[12+i]+=dl*camera[8+i]; }
    if (_back ) { _redraw=true; _recompute=true; for (int i=0;i<3;i++) camera[12+i]-=dl*camera[8+i]; }
    if (_recompute) compute_matrices();
    if (_redraw) draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key,TShiftState Shift) // this is called when key is pushed
    {
    //Caption=Key;
    if (Key==104) _left=true;
    if (Key==105) _right=true;
    if (Key==100) _forw=true;
    if (Key== 97) _back=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormKeyUp(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift) // this is called when key is released
    {
    if (Key==104) _left=false;
    if (Key==105) _right=false;
    if (Key==100) _forw=false;
    if (Key== 97) _back=false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here the Form header file (you do not really need it unless you are reconstructin my VCL app)

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef win_mainH
#define win_mainH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <ComCtrls.hpp>
#include <ExtCtrls.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TMain : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TTimer *tim_redraw;
    void __fastcall FormResize(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormPaint(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormDestroy(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall tim_redrawTimer(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift);
    void __fastcall FormKeyUp(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TMain(TComponent* Owner);
    void draw();

    int xs,ys,xs2,ys2,**pyx;
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;
    bool _redraw;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TMain *Main;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

The **VCL** app is just single Form with single timer (`100ms`) on it and no other **VCL** components. The `bmp` is just my **backbuffer** bitmap to avoid flickering. The keyboard events are just to enable turning and movement (with numpad `8,9,4,1`).

Here preview of above code:

[image: preview]

Now if you want to add the whiteout visibility limiter that is done by **Fog** or **Volumetric fog**. You simply interpolate between rendered color and White based on parameter `t`:

```
t = (z-znear)/(zfar-znear); // t = <0,1>
```

where `z` is pixel coordinate in camera space so:

```
color = color*(1.0-t) + White*t;
```

But to apply this in here we would need to encode the **2D** line rasterizer or have **2D** line api with per vertex color (like **OpenGL**). Another option is to fake it by blending in a Fog image which is fully solid near center line and fully transparent on the top and bottom edges.

Comment: Good! You help me a lot. I found another explanation that is called by Mode 7, the same method that SNES uses to create thperspective view mapping some texture. I will put my answer for it here.

Comment: @ViníciusBiavatti the raster techniques (texture pixel mappings) are usually based on  [Wolfenstein like raycasting techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32733650/2521214) ... for both walls and floor/ceiling

Answer (score 2):

I found the method that was used to create the perspective view in old games. Check my tutorial here: http://programandocoisas.blogspot.com.br/2017/09/mode-7.html.
The method's name is MODE 7. I made a tutorial to help wo wants to implement and understand it. The formula to make the mode 7 on a texture is:

```
_X = X / Z
_Y = Y / Z
```

Z you can use to create the depth. This variable is just an incremented variable on the Y coord. After get the _X and _Y new coords, just use these coords to get the pixel in the texture that will be mapped, and insert this pixel in X Y coord in the render view.

Here is the pseudo-code:
Basically, the pseudo code is it:

```
//This is the pseudo-code to generate the basic mode7

for each y in the view do
    y' <- y / z
    for each x in the view do
        x' <- x / z
        put x',y' texture pixel value in x,y view pixel
    end for
    z <- z + 1
end for
```

Here is the code:

```
package mode7;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * Mode 7 - Basic Implementation
 * This code will map a texture to create a pseudo-3d perspective.
 * This is an infinite render mode. The texture will be repeated without bounds.
 * @author VINICIUS
 */
public class BasicModeSeven {

    //Sizes
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int WIDTH_CENTER = WIDTH/2;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final int HEIGHT_CENTER = HEIGHT/2;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Create Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mode 7");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Create Buffered Images:
        //image - This is the image that will be printed in the render view
        //texture - This is the image that will be mapped to the render view
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        BufferedImage texture = ImageIO.read(new File("src/mode7/texture.png"));

        //The new coords that will be used to get the pixel on the texture
        double _x, _y;

        //z - the incrementable variable that beggins at -300 and go to 300, because 
        //the depth will be in the center of the HEIGHT
        double z =  HEIGHT_CENTER * -1;

        //Scales just to control de scale of the printed pixel. It is not necessary
        double scaleX = 16.0;
        double scaleY = 16.0; 

        //Mode 7 - loop (Left Top to Down)
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++){

            _y = y / z; //The new _y coord generated
            if(_y < 0)_y *= -1; //Control the _y because the z starting with a negative number
            _y *= scaleY; //Increase the size using scale
            _y %= texture.getHeight(); //Repeat the pixel avoiding get texture out of bounds 

            for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++){

                _x = (WIDTH_CENTER - x) / z; //The new _x coord generated
                if(_x < 0)_x *= -1; //Control the _x to dont be negative
                _x *= scaleX; //Increase the size using scale
                _x %= texture.getWidth(); //Repeat the pixel avoiding get texture out of bounds 

                //Set x,y of the view image with the _x,_y pixel in the texture
                image.setRGB(x, y, texture.getRGB((int)_x, (int)_y));
            }

            //Increment depth
            z++;
        }

        //Loop to render the generated image
        while(true){
            frame.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]