# Formula to evenly arrange lines on perspective imitation?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

In short: How to calculate h0...h4?

When imitating perspective, which formula is used to calculate h(0) to h(n) distances when known deformation values like either top-width-to-bottom-width ratio, or angle a (whichever parameter is useful for that)?

[image]

Comment: see [Perspective Vision on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219905/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

We can see perpective transformation having axial symmetry around vertical axis.

So transformation of rectangle with coordinates `(0,0)-(SrcWdt, SrcHgt)` with axial line at `SrcWdt/2`
[image]

gives trapezoid centered vertically with axial line at `DstWdt/2` and coordinates of right corners `RBX, RBY, RTX, RTY`

[image]

In this case transformation formulas are a bit simpler (than general case)

```
X' = DstXCenter + A * (X - XCenter) / (H * Y + 1)
Y' = (RBY +  E * Y) / (H * Y + 1)
```

And we can calculate coefficients `A, E, H` without solving of eight linear equation system using only coordinates of two corners of trapezoid.

Delphi code:

```
 procedure CalcAxialSymPersp(SrcWdt, SrcHgt, DstWdt, RBX, RBY, RTX, RTY: Integer;
                              var A, H, E: Double);
  begin
     A := (2 * RBX - DstWdt) / SrcWdt;
     H := (A * SrcWdt/ (2 * RTX - DstWdt) - 1) / SrcHgt;
     E := (RTY * (H * SrcHgt + 1) - RBY) / SrcHgt;
  end;
```

Having coefficients, we can apply transformation to any source point `PSrc` and get coordinates of mapped point. In your case `PSrc.X = 0` and `PSrc.Y = i * SrcHgt / 5 for i=1..4` will give Y-coordinates od horizontal lines.

```
procedure PerspMap(SrcWdt, DstWdt, RBY: Integer; A, H, E: Double; PSrc: TPoint): TPoint;
  begin
     Result.X := Round(DstWdt / 2 + A * (PSrc.X - SrcWdt/2) / (H * PSrc.Y + 1));
     Result.Y := Round((RBY +  E * PSrc.Y) / (H * PSrc.Y + 1));
  end;
```