# Efficient floor/ceiling rendering in Raycaster

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, raycasting

I am working on my Raycaster engine for some time, that I am runing on slower machines.
The most challenging problem I occures was/is the efficient floor and ceiling casting.

**My question is:
what other faster approached can I use?
(I am not sure how Doom floors and ceilings are rendered)**

So far I tried two typical solutions:

- verical and horizontal - casting as described in well know lodev tutorial: https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting2.html

The horizontal approach is of course much faster, but I additionally optimized it with fixed point variables.

Unfortunately even that approach is a performance killer - quite big fps drop even on faster cpus, and an slower cpus its a bottle neck.

My other ideas:

- I figure out an algorithm that was converting visible floor/ceiling map tiles to quads that I splitted to two triangles - and rasterized them as in regular scanline rasterizers. It was much faster - also I could sorted tiles by texture id to be more cache friendly. Unfortunately I got into "perspective correction texture mapping" in that case - to fix this I must add some divisions, that will lower the performacnce.. but also there are some optimalizations that can be done..

[image]

- using horizontal casting with every 2 ray (in column, row or both) - i will fill the blank spaces with averaged texture coords
- I could also try to combine my algorithm from 1 point with horizontal casting - I could sort the textures by ID then for example, I think that there would be no texture distortions
- mode 7 ?

my progres so far:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3zA2Wh0NB4

EDIT (1):

The Floor and Ceiling rednering code (based od lodev tutorial the horizontal approach)
but optimized with fixed point. Ceil calculations are mirrored to floor.

https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting2.html

This approach is faster than the vertical approach, butlots of calculations is inner loop and random accesing to texture pixels hits the performance..

```cpp
inline void RC_Raycast_Floor_Ceiling()
{
    // get local copy of RC_level_textures
    sBM_Bitmap* level_textures = RC_level_textures;

    // ray direction for leftmost ray (x = 0) and rightmost ray (x = width)
    float32 r_dx0 = RC_pp_dx - RC_pp_nsize_x_d2;
    float32 r_dy0 = RC_pp_dy - RC_pp_nsize_y_d2;

    //float32 r_dx1 = RC_pp_dx + RC_pp_nsize_x_d2;
    //float32 r_dy1 = RC_pp_dy + RC_pp_nsize_y_d2;

    // precalculated helpers for performance
    float32 r_dx1_m_dx0_div_width = (RC_pp_nsize_x_d2 + RC_pp_nsize_x_d2) * RC_render_width__1div__f;
    float32 r_dy1_m_dy0_div_width = (RC_pp_nsize_y_d2 + RC_pp_nsize_y_d2) * RC_render_width__1div__f;

    int16 ray_y = -1;
    u_int16 ray_y_counter = RC_render_height__i;

    u_int8* walls_buffer__ptr = RC_walls_buffer;

    // casting floor and ceiling - horizontal line by line - from left to right
    while(ray_y_counter)
    {
        ray_y++;
        ray_y_counter--;

        // dont go further if the current floor/ceil scanline line won't be visible
        if (ray_y >= RC_walls_start)
        {
            break;
            if (ray_y < RC_walls_end)
            {
                ray_y = RC_walls_end;
                ray_y_counter = RC_walls_start - 1;
                walls_buffer__ptr += ((RC_walls_end - RC_walls_start) * RC_render_width__i);
                continue;
            }
        }
      
        // whether this section is floor or ceiling
        u_int8 is_floor = ray_y > RC_render_height__div2__i;

        // current ray y position compared to the center of the screen (the horizon)
        float32 ry_pos = (float32)(is_floor ? (ray_y - RC_render_height__div2__i) : (RC_render_height__div2__i - ray_y));

        // vertical position of projection plane, 0.5 is between floor and ceiling
        float32 pp_z = (float32)(is_floor ? (RC_render_height__div2__i) : (RC_render_height__div2__i));

        float32 straight_distance_to_point = pp_z / ry_pos;

        // calculate the real world step vector we have to add for each x (parallel to camera plane)
        // adding step by step avoids multiplications with a weight in the inner loop
        float32 floor_step_x = straight_distance_to_point * r_dx1_m_dx0_div_width;
        float32 floor_step_y = straight_distance_to_point * r_dy1_m_dy0_div_width;

        float32 floor_x = RC_player_x + straight_distance_to_point * r_dx0;
        float32 floor_y = RC_player_y + straight_distance_to_point * r_dy0;

        // convert that values to fixed point
        int32 floor_x__fp = (int32)(floor_x * 65536.0f);
        int32 floor_y__fp = (int32)(floor_y * 65536.0f);

        int32 floor_step_x__fp = (int32)(floor_step_x * 65536.0f);
        int32 floor_step_y__fp = (int32)(floor_step_y * 65536.0f);

        u_int32 ry_m_render_width = ray_y * RC_render_width__i;
        u_int32 ry_m_render_width_i_mirror = (RC_render_height__i- ray_y-1) * RC_render_width__i;

        int16 ray_x = -1;
        u_int16 ray_x_counter = RC_render_width__i;

        sLV_Cell* level_map = RC_level->map;

        // drawing floor and ceiling from left to right
        while(ray_x_counter)
        {
            ray_x++;
            ray_x_counter--;

            floor_x__fp += floor_step_x__fp;
            floor_y__fp += floor_step_y__fp;

            if (*walls_buffer__ptr != 0)
            {
                walls_buffer__ptr++;
                continue;
            }

            walls_buffer__ptr++;

            u_int32 output_pixel_index = ray_x + ry_m_render_width;
            u_int32 output_pixel_index_mirror = ray_x + ry_m_render_width_i_mirror;

            // the cell coord is simply got from the integer parts of floorX and floorY

            u_int32 curr_cell_x = (floor_x__fp & FP_INTEGER_MASK_16) >> 16;
            u_int32 curr_cell_y = (floor_y__fp & FP_INTEGER_MASK_16) >> 16;

            // prevent overflow
           // curr_cell_x &= LV_MAP_SIZE_m1;
           // curr_cell_y &= LV_MAP_SIZE_m1;

            u_int32 texture_pixel_x = (floor_x__fp & FP_FRACTION_MASK_16) >> 9;
            u_int32 texture_pixel_y = (floor_y__fp & FP_FRACTION_MASK_16) >> 9;

            u_int32 cell_index = curr_cell_x + (curr_cell_y << LV_MAP_SIZE_BITSHIFT);

            // get the texture index depending on the cell
            u_int32 texture_index;

        /*    if (is_floor)
            {
               
                texture_index = level_map[cell_index].floor_id;
            }
            else
            {
                texture_index = level_map[cell_index].ceil_id;
            }*/

            texture_index = level_map[cell_index].ceil_id;

            // get pixel coords in texture
            u_int32 tex_index = texture_pixel_x + (texture_pixel_y << 7);
            u_int32 texture_current_pixel = level_textures[0].pixels[tex_index];

            RC_output_buffer_32[output_pixel_index] = texture_current_pixel;

            texture_index = level_map[cell_index].floor_id;
            texture_current_pixel = level_textures[texture_index].pixels[tex_index];

            RC_output_buffer_32[output_pixel_index_mirror] = texture_current_pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw as I was corrected in comments in here [What techniques were used to reduce the required re-rendering in 3D programs?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5903/6868) Doom did not use raycasting ... Also take alook at answers in here [Perspective Vision on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46195753/2521214) for some additional ideas

Comment: Hi @Spektre, the "problem" is that I am messing around with retro hardware, I mean Amiga, with modern 68k CPU in 320x240 or 640x480 at 32 bit mode. I get very Nice performance, but the floor/ceiling algorithm is so heavy that makes a bottleneck - probably because lots of calculations in the inner loop, non sorted  texture access etc. So I just looking for different approach. I could also use ammx instricts  functions but I dont know the assembler, maybe there will be some macros available that allow me to use it in C.

Comment: I am coding in C, no additional libs.. my code is portable and I check it on my PC and Amiga in the same time. On PC I got smooth ~100fps in 640x480x32, with textures and shading. Amiga is slower of course - my target there is get ~50fps I 320x200x32... but as I said the floor/ceilling horizontal algorithm from lodev is not very efficient. I optimized it a bit using fixed point and mirroring floor calculations to ceiling. The main problem is texture accesing in inner loop.

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for comment. I edited 1 post - adding rendering code. I didn't add it because as I said the approach is based on lodev tutorial - horizontal approiach.
https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting2.html
This approach makes some calculation in inner loop, whitch hits the performance, also the acces to textures is random (not sorted) that also hits the performance - I am looking for more optimal way..

Comment: @Spektre Hmm, thats seems interesting what You are saying - but I don't get it. Could You please explain me that algotihm more precisely. Thank You in advance :)

Comment: @Spektre Thank You, I am looking foreward to see the algorithms.. you don't have to put the code (maybe just fragments), I would like to understand the algorithm.. I am casting the walls before Floors, so I can save the calculations to reuse them. Did you test performance of both? I need faster one :)

Comment: Each approach has its pros and cons ... no rays renders always full screen regardless of how much coverage the walls has (so on big resolutions can be slower) , single ray per ceiling/floor/wall has more calculations  ... so you can not call one faster it all depends on a lot of factors ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will refer my ray cast engine so here some stuff that will help you understand it. Lets start with class declarations:

```cpp
const int   _Doom3D_mipmaps=8;          // number of mipmaps for texture
const DWORD _Doom3D_edit_cell_size=4;   // [pixel] 2D map cell size
const DWORD _Doom3D_cell_size=100;      // [units] cell cube size
//                                              heigh     ceil   floor  wall
const DWORD _Doom3D_cell_floor=(                0<<24)|( 0<<16)|(18<<8)|(39);
const DWORD _Doom3D_cell_wall =(_Doom3D_cell_size<<24)|( 0<<16)|( 0<<8)|(39);
class Texture2D // 2D textures
    {
public:
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;
    int xs,ys; DWORD **pyx;

    Texture2D() { bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap; xs=0; ys=0; pyx=NULL; resize(1,1); }
    Texture2D(Texture2D& a) { *this=a; }
    ~Texture2D() { free(); if (bmp) delete bmp; bmp=NULL; }
    Texture2D* operator = (const Texture2D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    Texture2D* operator = (const Texture2D &a) { bmp->Assign(a.bmp); resize(); return this; }

    void free() { if (pyx) delete[] pyx; xs=0; ys=0; pyx=NULL; }
    void resize(int _xs=-1,int _ys=-1) { free(); if ((_xs<0)||(_ys<0)) { _xs=bmp->Width; _ys=bmp->Height; } else bmp->SetSize(_xs,_ys); bmp->HandleType=bmDIB; bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit; pyx=new DWORD* [_ys]; for (int y=0;y<_ys;y++) pyx[y]=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y]; xs=bmp->Width; ys=bmp->Height; }
    void load(AnsiString name) { AnsiString ext=ExtractFileExt(name).LowerCase(); for(;;) { if (ext==".bmp") { bmp->LoadFromFile(name); break; } if (ext==".jpg") { TJPEGImage *jpg=new TJPEGImage; if (jpg==NULL) return; jpg->LoadFromFile(name); bmp->Assign(jpg); delete jpg; break; } return; } resize(); }
    };
class Doom3D
    {
public:
    Texture2D map,map2,scr,sky;         // map, map preview, screen, sky texture
    Texture2D txr[_Doom3D_mipmaps],*ptxr;// texture atlas with mipmas, actual mipmap for rendering scan lines
    DWORD sxs2,sys2;                    // screen half resolution
    DWORD tn,tm;                        // number of textures in texture atlas, number of mipmaps used
    BYTE liH[256],liV[256],liF[256];    // shading LUT for H,V,floor/ceiling (light scaled shades of gray)

    int scale_x;
    bool _no_mipmap;

    struct _player
        {
        double  a;                      // player view direction [rad]
        double x0,y0,z0;                // old player position [cell]
        double  x, y, z;                // player position [cell]
        double vx,vy,vz;                // player speed [cell/s]
        double ax,ay,az;                // player acceleration [cell/s]
        void update(double dt)
            {
            x0=x; vx+=ax*dt; x+=vx*dt;
            y0=y; vy+=ay*dt; y+=vy*dt;
            z0=z; vz+=az*dt; z+=vz*dt;
            }
        _player() { a=x=y=z=vx=vy=vz=ax=ay=az=0.0; }
        _player(_player& a) { *this=a; }
        ~_player() {};
        _player* operator = (const _player *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
        //_player* operator = (const _player &a) { ..copy... return this; }
        } plr;
    double view_ang;                    // [rad] view angle
    double focus;                       // [cells] view focal length
    double wall;                        // [px] projected wall size ratio size = height*wall/distance
    struct _ray
        {
        int    x,y;                     // cell map position
        double ang;                     // ray angle
        double x0,y0,l0;                // cell first hit
        double x1,y1,l1;                // cell second hit
        int    sx;                      // screen x coordinate
        int    sy0,sy1;                 // screen y coordinates of V scanline to render
        char tp0,tp1;                   // H/V hit type
        DWORD map;                      // map cell of hit or 0xFFFFFFFF
        _ray() {};
        _ray(_ray& a)   { *this=a; }
        ~_ray() {};
        _ray* operator = (const _ray *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
        //_ray* operator = (const _ray &a) { ..copy... return this; }
        };

    keytab keys;                        // keyboard handler
    DWORD txr_wall;                     // map editor
    DWORD txr_floor;
    DWORD txr_ceil;
    DWORD cell_h;
    DWORD *txr_mode; AnsiString txr_mode_txt;

    Doom3D();
    Doom3D(Doom3D& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~Doom3D();
    Doom3D* operator = (const Doom3D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //Doom3D* operator = (const Doom3D &a) { ..copy... return this; }

    void map_resize(DWORD xs,DWORD ys); // change map resolution
    void map_clear();                   // clear whole map
    void map_save(AnsiString name);     // save map to file
    void map_load(AnsiString name);     // load map from file
    void scr_resize(DWORD xs,DWORD ys); // resize view
    void txr_mipmap();                  // generate mipmaps for txr

    bool cell2screen(int &sx,int &sy,double x,double y,double z);   // [pixel] <- [cell] return tru if in front of player
    void draw_scanline(int sx,int sy0,int sy1,                int symin,int tx0,int ty0,int tx1,int ty1,BYTE *li); // render screen y-scan line from texture (sub routine)
    void draw_scanline(int sx,int sy0,int sy1,int sz0,int sz1,int symin,int tx0,int ty0,int tx1,int ty1,BYTE *li); // render screen y-scan line from texture (sub routine)
    void draw_cell(_ray &p);            // render actual cell hit by ray p (sub routine)
    void draw();                        // render view
    void update(double dt);             // update game logic (call in timer with interval dt [s])
    void mouse(double x,double y,TShiftState sh)    // editor mouse handler
        {
        keys.setm(x,y,sh);  // mx,my mouse screen pos [pixels]
        x=floor(x/_Doom3D_edit_cell_size); //if (x>=map.xs) x=map.xs-1; if (x<0) x=0;
        y=floor(y/_Doom3D_edit_cell_size); //if (y>=map.ys) y=map.ys-1; if (y<0) y=0;
        DWORD xx=x,yy=y;
        if ((xx>=0)&&(xx<map.xs)&&(yy>=0)&&(yy<map.ys)) keys.setk(xx,yy,sh); // kx,ky mouse map pos [cells]
        xx=keys.kx; yy=keys.ky;
        if (keys.Shift.Contains(ssLeft  )) map.pyx[yy][xx]=(txr_wall)|(txr_floor<<8)|(txr_ceil<<16)|(cell_h<<24);
        if (keys.Shift.Contains(ssRight )) map.pyx[yy][xx]=0xFFFFFFFF;
        if (keys.Shift.Contains(ssMiddle))
            {
            DWORD c=map.pyx[yy][xx];
            txr_wall  =c     &0xFF;
            txr_floor=(c>> 8)&0xFF;
            txr_ceil =(c>>16)&0xFF;
            cell_h   =(c>>24)&0xFF;
            }
        keys.rfsmouse();
        }
    void wheel(int delta,TShiftState sh)    // editor mouse wheel handler
        {
        if (sh.Contains(ssShift))
            {
            if (delta<0) { cell_h-=10; if (cell_h>_Doom3D_cell_size) cell_h=0; }
            if (delta>0) { cell_h+=10; if (cell_h>_Doom3D_cell_size) cell_h=_Doom3D_cell_size; }
            }
        else{
            if (delta<0) { (*txr_mode)--; if (*txr_mode>=tn) *txr_mode=tn-1; }
            if (delta>0) { (*txr_mode)++; if (*txr_mode==tn) *txr_mode=   0; }
            }
        }
    };
```

The full code (without any helper files) is ~27.7 KByte so it would not fit with answer. Its old version (without floor/ceiling/top of walls) is here:

- [Ray Casting with different height size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214)

Its more complicated than yours as it allows walls with different heights and separate texture for wall, floor and ceiling (however ceiling is not implemented yet I used cloud texture instead) and also jumps (`z` position of player).

The geometry of map and projections are the same as in the link above. Here a helper function that convert between 2.5D map position and screen (so you know what math is used):

```cpp
bool Doom3D::cell2screen(int &sx,int &sy,double x,double y,double z)
    {
    double a,l;
    // x,y relative to player
    x-=plr.x;
    y-=plr.y;
    // convert z from [cell] to units
    z*=_Doom3D_cell_size;
    // angle -> sx
    a=atanxy(x,y)-plr.a;
    if (a<-pi) a+=pi2;
    if (a>+pi) a-=pi2;
    sx=double(sxs2)*(1.0+(2.0*a/view_ang));
    // perpendicular distance -> sy
    l=sqrt((x*x)+(y*y))*cos(a);
    sy=sys2+divide((double((2.0*plr.z+1.0)*_Doom3D_cell_size)-z-z)*wall,l);
    // in front of player?
    return (fabs(a)<=0.5*pi);
    }
```

The function itself is used only for HUD of editor (highlight selected map cell in 2.5D view) the `sxs2,sys2` is the center of screen (half of resolution `sxs,sys`) and `wall` is used to manage the perspective projection computed like this:

```cpp
void Doom3D::scr_resize(DWORD xs,DWORD ys)
    {
    scr.resize(xs,ys);
    sxs2=scr.xs>>1;
    sys2=scr.ys>>1;
    // aspect ratio,view angle corrections
    double a=90.0*deg-view_ang;
    wall=double(scr.xs)*(1.25+(0.288*a)+(2.04*a*a))*focus/double(_Doom3D_cell_size);
    }
```

In my engine the ray is tested in more like ray march manner as it does not stop on first hit, but on first hit that covers whole wall size (so rays can pass through smaller walls that do not block whole view which also render the ground tiles along the way).

As your engine does not do this and have full size walls only you will have just single hit instead.

Now finally get back to your question. I see 2 ways of improvement:

1. **use result of the ray from wall test instead of casting floor/ceiling ray**

   As you want to have separate tiles on ceiling and floor then you should use ray marching like ray cast. Meaning cast one ray per each column of screen and iterate it by all map cell crossings until a wall is hit. However instead of rendering only on wall hit you have to render on each cell hit. Something like on this image:

   [image: ray march]

   So red line is cast ray (orange is just a mirror). Each rendered cell of map is hit with the ray in 2 points. You should know the map cell position of each hit and also its screen coordinate from the ray casting. So you just need to add the perpendicular distance to camera and render the line segment as a perspective correct interpolated textured line for floor and ceiling. The wall is always just vertical non perspective textured line. The texture coordinates are taken from the map position of hit (fractional part of coordinates). In code its a bit messy but here it is:

   ```cpp
    void Doom3D::draw_scanline(int sx,int sy0,int sy1,int symin,int tx0,int ty0,int tx1,int ty1,BYTE *li)
        {
        // affine texture mapping (front side of walls) sy0>sy1
        union { DWORD dd; BYTE db[4]; } cc;
        int sy,tx,ty,ktx,kty,dtx,dty,ctx,cty,dsy;
               dsy=sy1-sy0; if (dsy<0)                        dsy=-dsy;
        ktx=0; dtx=tx1-tx0; if (dtx>0) ktx=+1; else { ktx=-1; dtx=-dtx; } tx=tx0; ctx=0;
        kty=0; dty=ty1-ty0; if (dty>0) kty=+1; else { kty=-1; dty=-dty; } ty=ty0; cty=0;
        if (dsy) for (sy=sy0;sy>=sy1;sy--)
            {
            if ((sy>=0)&&(sy<scr.ys)&&(sy<=symin))
             if ((tx>=0)&&(tx<ptxr->xs)&&(ty>=0)&&(ty<ptxr->ys))
                {
                cc.dd=ptxr->pyx[ty][tx];
                cc.db[0]=li[cc.db[0]];
                cc.db[1]=li[cc.db[1]];
                cc.db[2]=li[cc.db[2]];
                scr.pyx[sy][sx]=cc.dd;
                }
            for (ctx+=dtx;ctx>=dsy;) { ctx-=dsy; tx+=ktx; }
            for (cty+=dty;cty>=dsy;) { cty-=dsy; ty+=kty; }
            }
        }
    void Doom3D::draw_scanline(int sx,int sy0,int sy1,int sz0,int sz1,int symin,int tx0,int ty0,int tx1,int ty1,BYTE *li)
        {
        // perspective correct mapping (floor, top side of walls, ceiling) sy0>sy1
        union { DWORD dd; BYTE db[4]; } cc;
        int sy,tx,ty,dsy,dtx,dty,n,dn;
        int a,_z0,_z1,_tx;
        const int acc0=16;
        const int acc1=8;
        _tx=tx0-(tx0%ptxr->ys);
        tx0-=_tx;
        tx1-=_tx;
        dsy=sy1-sy0; dn=abs(dsy);
        dtx=tx1-tx0;
        dty=ty1-ty0;
        if (sz0==0) return; _z0=(1<<acc0)/sz0;
        if (sz1==0) return; _z1=(1<<acc0)/sz1;
        if (dn) for (n=0;n<=dn;n++)
            {
            sy=sy0+((n*dsy)/dn);
            a=((n<<acc1)*_z1)/(((dn-n)*_z0)+(n*_z1)); // perspective correction a=<0,1<<acc1> (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping)
            tx=tx0+((a*dtx)>>acc1)+_tx;
            ty=ty0+((a*dty)>>acc1);
            if ((sy>=0)&&(sy<scr.ys)&&(sy<=symin))
             if ((tx>=0)&&(tx<ptxr->xs)&&(ty>=0)&&(ty<ptxr->ys))
                {
                cc.dd=ptxr->pyx[ty][tx];
                cc.db[0]=li[cc.db[0]];
                cc.db[1]=li[cc.db[1]];
                cc.db[2]=li[cc.db[2]];
                scr.pyx[sy][sx]=cc.dd;
                }
            }
        }
    void Doom3D::draw_cell(_ray &p)
        {
        BYTE *li;
        DWORD m;
        int tx0,tx1,ty0,ty1,sy,sy0,sy1,sy2,sy3,sz0,sz1,q;
        int sy4,sy5;
        //sy0>=sy1
        sy0=sys2+divide(double((1.0+2.0*plr.z)*_Doom3D_cell_size)*wall,p.l0);
        sy1=sy0 -divide(double((p.map>>24)<<1                   )*wall,p.l0);
        sy2=sys2+divide(double((1.0+2.0*plr.z)*_Doom3D_cell_size)*wall,p.l1);
        sy3=sy2 -divide(double((p.map>>24)<<1                   )*wall,p.l1);
        sy4=sys2-divide(double((1.0-2.0*plr.z)*_Doom3D_cell_size)*wall,p.l1);
        sy5=sys2-divide(double((1.0-2.0*plr.z)*_Doom3D_cell_size)*wall,p.l0);
        sz0=double(p.l0*_Doom3D_cell_size);
        sz1=double(p.l1*_Doom3D_cell_size);
        // select mipmap resolution
        ty0=divide(double(_Doom3D_cell_size<<1)*wall,p.l0);
        for (q=tm-1;q>=0;q--)
            {
            ptxr=txr+q;
            if (ty0<=ptxr->ys) break;
            }
        if (_no_mipmap) ptxr=txr;
        // mouse select
        if (p.sx==round(keys.mx))
         if (keys.my>=sy3)
          if (keys.my<=sy0)
           if ((keys.my>=map2.ys)||(keys.mx>=map2.xs))
            {
            keys.kx=p.x;
            keys.ky=p.y;
            }
        if ((p.map&0xFF)==0xFF) { sy1=sy0; sy3=sy2; }
        // wall
        if ((sy1<p.sy1)&&((p.map&0xFF)!=0xFF))
            {
            tx0=ptxr->ys*(p.map&0xFF);
            if (p.tp0=='H') { li=liH; tx0+=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.x0-floor(p.x0))); }
            if (p.tp0=='V') { li=liV; tx0+=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.y0-floor(p.y0))); }
            draw_scanline(p.sx,sy0,sy1,p.sy1,tx0,0,tx0,((p.map>>24)*(ptxr->ys-1))/_Doom3D_cell_size,li);
            p.sy1=sy1;
            }
        // ceiling
        if ((p.map&0xFF0000)!=0xFF0000)
            {
            q=ptxr->ys*((p.map>>16)&0xFF);
            tx0=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.x0-double(p.x)))+q;
            ty0=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.y0-double(p.y)));
            tx1=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.x1-double(p.x)))+q;
            ty1=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.y1-double(p.y)));
            draw_scanline(p.sx,sy5,sy4,sz0,sz1,p.sy1,tx0,ty0,tx1,ty1,liF);
            }
        // floor/top side
        if ((sy3<p.sy1)&&((p.map&0xFF00)!=0xFF00))
            {
            q=ptxr->ys*((p.map>>8)&0xFF);
            tx0=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.x0-double(p.x)))+q;
            ty0=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.y0-double(p.y)));
            tx1=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.x1-double(p.x)))+q;
            ty1=double(double(ptxr->ys-1)*(p.y1-double(p.y)));
            draw_scanline(p.sx,sy1,sy3,sz0,sz1,p.sy1,tx0,ty0,tx1,ty1,liF);
            p.sy1=sy3;
            }
        if (sy3<p.sy1) p.sy1=sy3;
        }
    void Doom3D::draw()
        {
        tbeg();
        _ray p;
        DWORD x,y,c,m;
        DWORD mx,mx0,mx1;
        DWORD my,my0,my1;
        double a,a0,da,dx,dy,l;
        double xx0,yy0,dx0,dy0,ll0,dl0;
        double xx1,yy1,dx1,dy1,ll1,dl1;

        // compute diffuse + ambient lighting LUT (light scaled shades of gray)
        c=155.0+fabs(100.0*sin(   plr.a)); for (x=0;x<256;x++) liH[x]=(x*c)>>8; // H wall
        c=155.0+fabs(100.0*cos(   plr.a)); for (x=0;x<256;x++) liV[x]=(x*c)>>8; // V wall
        c=155.0+fabs(100.0*cos(30.0*deg)); for (x=0;x<256;x++) liF[x]=(x*c)>>8; // floor, wall top side

        // [2D map]
        m=_Doom3D_edit_cell_size;
        for (my0=0,my1=m,y=0;y<map.ys;y++,my0=my1,my1+=m)   // map.pyx[][]
         for (mx0=0,mx1=m,x=0;x<map.xs;x++,mx0=mx1,mx1+=m)
            {
            c=0x00010101*((0x40+(0x40*(map.pyx[y][x]>>24)))/_Doom3D_cell_size);
            for (my=my0;my<my1;my++)
             for (mx=mx0;mx<mx1;mx++)
              map2.pyx[my][mx]=c;
            }
        c=0x00202020;                                       // map grid
        for (y=0;y<map2.ys;y+=m) for (x=0;x<map2.xs;x++) map2.pyx[y][x]=c;
        for (x=0;x<map2.xs;x+=m) for (y=0;y<map2.ys;y++) map2.pyx[y][x]=c;
        x=keys.kx*m;                                        // selected cell
        y=keys.ky*m;
        map2.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=0x0020FFFF;
        map2.bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x  ,y  );
        map2.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x+m,y  );
        map2.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x+m,y+m);
        map2.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x  ,y+m);
        map2.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x  ,y  );
        map2.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Mode=pmMerge;

        // [cast rays]
        a0=plr.a-(0.5*view_ang);
        da=divide(view_ang,scr.xs-1);
        da*=scale_x;
        for (a=a0,x=0;x<scr.xs;x+=scale_x,a+=da)
            {
            // grid V-line hits
            ll0=1.0e20; dl0=0.0; dx0=cos(a); const char tp0='V';
            if (dx0<0.0) { xx0=floor(plr.x); dx0=-1.0; }
            if (dx0>0.0) { xx0=ceil (plr.x); dx0=+1.0; }
            if (fabs(dx0)>1e-6) { dy0=tan(a); yy0=plr.y+((xx0-plr.x)*dy0);             dy0*=dx0; dx=xx0-plr.x; dy=yy0-plr.y; ll0=sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy)); dl0=sqrt((dx0*dx0)+(dy0*dy0)); }
            // grid H-line hits
            ll1=1.0e20; dl1=0.0; dy1=sin(a); const char tp1='H';
            if (dy1<0.0) { yy1=floor(plr.y); dy1=-1.0; }
            if (dy1>0.0) { yy1=ceil (plr.y); dy1=+1.0; }
            if (fabs(dy1)>1e-6) { dx1=divide(1.0,tan(a)); xx1=plr.x+((yy1-plr.y)*dx1); dx1*=dy1; dx=xx1-plr.x; dy=yy1-plr.y; ll1=sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy)); dl1=sqrt((dx1*dx1)+(dy1*dy1)); }
            p.ang=a;
            p.sx =x;
            p.sy0=scr.ys;
            p.sy1=scr.ys;
            // first hit
            if (ll0<ll1){ p.tp0=tp0; p.x0=xx0; p.y0=yy0; p.l0=ll0; xx0+=dx0; yy0+=dy0; ll0+=dl0; }
             else       { p.tp0=tp1; p.x0=xx1; p.y0=yy1; p.l0=ll1; xx1+=dx1; yy1+=dy1; ll1+=dl1; }
            p.l0*=cos(p.ang-plr.a); // anti fish eye
            p.map=0xFFFFFFFF; p.x=p.x0; p.y=p.y0;
            for (;;)
                {
                // closest hit
                if (ll0<ll1) { p.tp1=tp0; p.x1=xx0; p.y1=yy0; p.l1=ll0; xx0+=dx0; yy0+=dy0; ll0+=dl0; }
                 else        { p.tp1=tp1; p.x1=xx1; p.y1=yy1; p.l1=ll1; xx1+=dx1; yy1+=dy1; ll1+=dl1; }
                p.x=floor(0.5*(p.x0+p.x1)); // actaul cell position
                p.y=floor(0.5*(p.y0+p.y1));
                p.l1*=cos(p.ang-plr.a);     // anti fish eye
                // edge of map crossed?
                if ((p.x>=0)&&(p.x<map.xs)&&(p.y>=0)&&(p.y<map.ys)) p.map=map.pyx[p.y][p.x]; else break;
                // render
                draw_cell(p);               // scan line
                if (p.sy1<=0) break;        // scan line reached top of screen
                // prepare next cell position
                p.tp0=p.tp1; p.x0=p.x1; p.y0=p.y1; p.l0=p.l1;
                }
            // copy skiped scan lines
            for (mx=1;mx<scale_x;mx++)
             if (x+mx<scr.xs)
              for (y=0;y<scr.ys;y++)
               scr.pyx[y][x+mx]=scr.pyx[y][x];
            // render map ray
            if (x==sxs2)                   map2.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=0x000000FF;
            if ((x==0)||(x==sxs2+scale_x)) map2.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=0x00002020;
            map2.bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(plr.x*m,plr.y*m);
            map2.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(p.x1*m,p.y1*m);
            }
        map2.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Mode=pmCopy;
        map2.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=0x000000FF;
        map2.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=0x000000FF;
        c=focus*m;
        map2.bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(plr.x*m-c,plr.y*m-c,plr.x*m+c,plr.y*m+c);
        scr.bmp->Canvas->Draw(0,0,map2.bmp);
        // ... here HUD and info texts continues I skipped it to keep this simple
        }
   ```
2. **render floor and ceiling without per pixel of row/col raycast**

   Simple ray casters do use non textured floor/ceiling which makes this simple just render half of screen with sky and the other with ground color before rendering the walls (or after it if rendered walls start and end is remembered):

   [image: no texture floor/ceiling]

   something like this in code:

   ```cpp
    int x,y,sxs=sxs2<<1,sys=sys2<<1;
    // simple color sky/ceiling
    for (y=0;y<sys2;y++)
     for (x=0;x<sxs;x++)
      scr.pyx[y][x]=0x000080FF;
     for (y=sys2;y<sys;y++)
      for (x=0;x<sxs;x++)
       scr.pyx[y][x]=0x00404040;
   ```

   To make this more nice usually for outdoor parts of map sky texture is added that covers the ceiling. It does not move with player just rotates. So you can map a sky textured quad to upper half of view that just rotates with `-plr.a` Here overview of the geometry:

   [image: sky single texture]

   The bigger radius `R` is half of texture resolution and the smaller I empirically compute by `r=R*sin(0.5*view_ang)` as its looking best to me (however the true value should be computed from screen aspect ratio and perspective focal length and `view_ang`).

   Here some code for this:

   ```cpp
        const int x0=0,x1=sxs2<<1,y0=0,y1=sys2,y2=sys2<<1;
        int sx[4]={x0,x0,x1,x1},
            sy[4]={y0,y1,y1,y0},
            tx[4],ty[4],dx,dy;
        float a,r,R;
        R=sky.xs>>1;            // sky texture inscribed circle radius
        r=R*sin(0.5*view_ang);  // smaller radius (visible portion of sky)
        dx=sky.xs>>1;           // mid of sky texture
        dy=sky.ys>>1;
        a=plr.a-(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[0]=float(R*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[0]=float(R*sin(a))+dy;
        a=plr.a-(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[1]=float(r*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[1]=float(r*sin(a))+dy;
        a=plr.a+(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[2]=float(r*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[2]=float(r*sin(a))+dy;
        a=plr.a+(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[3]=float(R*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[3]=float(R*sin(a))+dy;
        polygon2D(scr,sky,sx,sy,tx,ty,4);
   ```

   The ground (and indoor ceiling) can be done similarly but the radius `R` must be a fraction of whole texture. The player position in map must be scaled to texture `half size - R` and added to the texture coordinates. However the texture resolution must be big enough otherwise it will not look as good (Ideally the empty space should match the resolution of your map size * wall texture resolution... So if `R` is half the empty space will be also `R` then its done like this:

   ```cpp
        const int x0=0,x1=sxs2<<1,y0=0,y1=sys2,y2=sys2<<1;
        int sx[4]={x0,x0,x1,x1},
            sy[4]={y1,y2,y2,y1},
            tx[4],ty[4],i,dx,dy,dr;
        float a,r,R;
        R=sky.xs>>2;            // sky texture inscribed circle radius /2 so empty space is also R
        r=R*sin(0.5*view_ang);  // smaller radius (visible portion of sky)
        dx=sky.xs>>1;           // mid of sky texture
        dy=sky.ys>>1;
        a=float(R)/float(map.xs);   // add player position skaled to empty space
        dx+=float(plr.x*a);
        dy+=float(plr.y*a);
        a=plr.a-(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[0]=float(R*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[0]=float(R*sin(a))+dy;
        a=plr.a-(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[1]=float(r*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[1]=float(r*sin(a))+dy;
        a=plr.a+(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[2]=float(r*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[2]=float(r*sin(a))+dy;
        a=plr.a+(0.5*view_ang);
        tx[3]=float(R*cos(a))+dx;
        ty[3]=float(R*sin(a))+dy;
        polygon2D(scr,sky,sx,sy,tx,ty,4);
   ```

   In case you want to use smaller textures then your polygon rendering must be capable of handling texture coordinates like `GL_REPEAT` in OpenGL. The function `polygon2D(scr,sky,sx,sy,tx,ty,4)` is just simple/ugly/slow/unoptimized 2D textured polygon render I bustled yesterday just to test this (as I did not want to mess my optimized rendering routines for #1 methods which support only scan lines instead of polygons anyway) where `sx,sy` are array of screen coordinates, `tx,ty` are arrays f texture coordinates, `4` is number of vertexes and `scr,txr` are target and source textures. The code is just a port of this [`fill_quad`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66507640/2521214) without the shadings and SSD1306 related stuff. Here full code:

   ```cpp
    const int ys_max=1024;
    int bufl_vx[ys_max],bufr_vx[ys_max];
    int bufl_tx[ys_max],bufr_tx[ys_max];
    int bufl_ty[ys_max],bufr_ty[ys_max];
    void _fill2D_line(Texture2D &scr,Texture2D &txr,int vx0,int vy0,int tx0,int ty0,int vx1,int vy1,int tx1,int ty1)
        {
        int *bvx,*btx,*bty;
        int i,n,cvx,cvy,ctx,cty,svx,svy,stx,sty;
        // target buffer depend on y direction (before point ordering)
        if (vy0<vy1){ bvx=bufl_vx; btx=bufl_tx; bty=bufl_ty; }
         else       { bvx=bufr_vx; btx=bufr_tx; bty=bufr_ty; }
        // order points so joined edges are interpolated the same way
        if (vx0>vx1)
            {
            i=vx0; vx0=vx1; vx1=i;
            i=vy0; vy0=vy1; vy1=i;
            i=tx0; tx0=tx1; tx1=i;
            i=ty0; ty0=ty1; ty1=i;
            }
        // line DDA parameters
        vx1-=vx0; svx=0; if (vx1>0) svx=+1; if (vx1<0) { svx=-1; vx1=-vx1; } if (vx1) vx1++;            n=vx1;
        vy1-=vy0; svy=0; if (vy1>0) svy=+1; if (vy1<0) { svy=-1; vy1=-vy1; } if (vy1) vy1++; if (n<vy1) n=vy1;
        tx1-=tx0; stx=0; if (tx1>0) stx=+1; if (tx1<0) { stx=-1; tx1=-tx1; } if (tx1) tx1++; if (n<tx1) n=tx1;
        ty1-=ty0; sty=0; if (ty1>0) sty=+1; if (ty1<0) { sty=-1; ty1=-ty1; } if (ty1) ty1++; if (n<ty1) n=ty1;
        // single pixel (not a line)
        if (!n)
            {
            if ((vy0>=0)&&(vy0<scr.ys))
                {
                bufl_vx[vy0]=vx0; bufl_tx[vy0]=tx0; bufl_ty[vy0]=ty0;
                bufr_vx[vy0]=vx0; bufr_tx[vy0]=tx0; bufr_ty[vy0]=ty0;
                }
            return;
            }
        // horizontal line
        if (svy==0) return;
        // ND DDA algo i is parameter
        for (cvx=cvy=ctx=cty=n,i=0;;)
            {
            if ((vy0>=0)&&(vy0<scr.ys)){ bvx[vy0]=vx0; btx[vy0]=tx0; bty[vy0]=ty0; }
            i++; if (i>=n) break;
            cvx-=vx1; if (cvx<=0){ cvx+=n; vx0+=svx; }
            cvy-=vy1; if (cvy<=0){ cvy+=n; vy0+=svy; }
            ctx-=tx1; if (ctx<=0){ ctx+=n; tx0+=stx; }
            cty-=ty1; if (cty<=0){ cty+=n; ty0+=sty; }
            }
        }
    void _fill2D(Texture2D &scr,Texture2D &txr,int Y0,int Y1)
        {
        int vx0,vx1,tx0,tx1,ty0,ty1;
        int vy,i,n,cvx,ctx,cty,svx,stx,sty;
        // fill horizontal lines
        for (vy=Y0;vy<=Y1;vy++)
            {
            // horizontal line to render
            vx0=bufl_vx[vy]; tx0=bufl_tx[vy]; ty0=bufl_ty[vy];
            vx1=bufr_vx[vy]; tx1=bufr_tx[vy]; ty1=bufr_ty[vy];
            if ((vx0<      0)||(vx1<      0)) continue;
            if ((vx0<      0)&&(vx1<      0)) continue;
            if ((vx0>=scr.xs)&&(vx1>=scr.xs)) continue;
            // line DDA parameters
            vx1-=vx0; svx=0; if (vx1>0) svx=+1; if (vx1<0) { svx=-1; vx1=-vx1; } if (vx1) vx1++;            n=vx1;
            tx1-=tx0; stx=0; if (tx1>0) stx=+1; if (tx1<0) { stx=-1; tx1=-tx1; } if (tx1) tx1++; if (n<tx1) n=tx1;
            ty1-=ty0; sty=0; if (ty1>0) sty=+1; if (ty1<0) { sty=-1; ty1=-ty1; } if (ty1) ty1++; if (n<ty1) n=ty1;
            // single pixel (not a line)
            if (!n)
                {
                if ((vx0>=0)&&(vx0<scr.xs)) scr.pyx[vy][vx0]=txr.pyx[ty0][tx0];
                continue;
                }
            // ND DDA algo i is parameter
            for (cvx=ctx=cty=n,i=0;;)
                {
                while (tx0<0) tx0+=txr.xs;
                while (ty0<0) ty0+=txr.ys;
                while (tx0>=txr.xs) tx0-=txr.xs;
                while (ty0>=txr.ys) ty0-=txr.ys;
                if ((vx0>=0)&&(vx0<scr.xs)) scr.pyx[vy][vx0]=txr.pyx[ty0][tx0];
                i++; if (i>=n) break;
                cvx-=vx1; if (cvx<=0){ cvx+=n; vx0+=svx; }
                ctx-=tx1; if (ctx<=0){ ctx+=n; tx0+=stx; }
                cty-=ty1; if (cty<=0){ cty+=n; ty0+=sty; }
                }
            }
        }
    void polygon2D(Texture2D &scr,Texture2D &txr,int *vx,int *vy,int *tx,int *ty,int n)
        {
        int i,j,y,Y0,Y1;
        // y range to render
        Y0=Y1=vy[0];
        for (i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
            if (Y0>vy[i]) Y0=vy[i];
            if (Y1<vy[i]) Y1=vy[i];
            }
        // clip to screen in y axis
        if ((Y1<0)||(Y0>=scr.ys)) return;
        if (Y0<      0) Y0=       0;
        if (Y1>=scr.ys) Y1=scr.ys-1;
        // clear buffers
        for (y=Y0;y<=Y1;y++)
            {
            bufl_vx[y]=-1;
            bufr_vx[y]=-1;
            }
        // render circumference
        for (j=n-1,i=0;i<n;j=i,i++)
         _fill2D_line(scr,txr,vx[i],vy[i],tx[i],ty[i],vx[j],vy[j],tx[j],ty[j]);
        // fill horizontal lines
        _fill2D(scr,txr,Y0,Y1);
        }
   ```

   And finally preview (using sky texture for both sky and ground):

   [image: single textured quad]

   The render does not have perspective correct interpolation but for single big texture its not a big problem. In case you want also jumps then you need recompute `R,r` with the use of `z` position of player or use Another option to compute the texture coordinates by simply casting 4 rays (one for each corner of half screen rectangle) and check where it hit map edges.

   The math behind can be found in here:

   - [Perspective Vision on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46195753/2521214)
   - [How to show visible part of planar world rendered with 3D perspective on topside 2D minimap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52475105/2521214)

   However beware your perspective must match the ray cast otherwise alignment artifacts may occur (or ground move with slightly different speed than walls).

Comment: Thank You @Spectre, I going to study it, my Raycaster also can have different textures per tile in walls and floora and ceil (as in my youtube video) - that is also performance hit because I need to check every pixel what tile is on and select proper texture.. but yes. the floor will remain only one heigh - not planning to do different height size

Comment: @Mateusz I updated my answer. #2 is finished. Will continue with #1 later on but not today have a lot on my plate right now as  Finally the weather is better so I can function. Was going in circles yesterday because of it for hours. And today this was done before breakfast :)  The older I get the more dependent on weather I am.

Comment: Hello @Spektre, thanks again! Hudge amout of knowledge! Yes the sky box itself and non textured floor (or even distance shaded) is a big speed-up.. there is a very interesting project called 'Dread' (Doom clone) for standard Amiga 500 that is using similar approach I mean - sky + non textured floor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c00B3uE5FV8

I am looking foreward to see Your solution on that textured version - that my goal :) I spent some time looking and testing different approaches and now I lack of ideas. :)

Comment: @Mateusz I added the **#1** with working code (more or less optimized) with the ceiling implemented. I already hit the 30K  limit so I can not add more (have to delete some formatting lines and reword text to fit) the only thing left to my engine is to render the sky texture in case ceiling texture is set to blank ...

Comment: wow, thats a very nice idea.. must analyze it closely.. thank you very much for your time and explanations, I hope that algorithm will help me improving my engine! :)

Comment: @Mateusz I finished implementing the new stuff from this answer (needed some tweaks to remove glitches with original editation and rendering) into my engine here [win32 stand alone demo](https://ulozto.net/file/ldRBVyQ0PdFI/doom3d-exe-zip#!ZGExAmR2ZGH5ATD1AmWxZ2H5AJH1BRyTMSOLL3csrH9bITAyZj==) in txt file are the keyboard and mouse functions described just remember to turn on/off the editor by  `[E]` key... The demo has just simple 32x32 map showing its features (variable height walls, different texture for floor,sky,wall even blank and global sky texture for blank ceilings

Comment: Hello, thanks for the file I will check it out. Meanwhile I figureout a global optimalization 'trick'. Since my textures are 128x128 they dont need to be in true color- indexed color will be enought, ex. 256 colors.. I can then precompute color tables for 256 intensities values 0-255 and use it for distance shading. Right now I am splitying my 4byte color into separate r,g,b - taking intensity for each and put it back to 4byte value. Its 7 operations + 3 array calls. With indexed color I have only 0 operations just 1 array call..

Comment: @Mateusz yep ... I do not use index color as on VCL I do not have any fast support for this so true color is my only option ... hence the slower 3x LUT access instead of one on per pixel basis... however new CPU architecture compensate this with paralelization ...