# How do I properly decide on the number of diffracted rays in a ray tracer?

Tags: computational-geometry, raytracing

Small heads up: I'm not sure this is the proper forum for this question; I saw other people asking about ray tracers here, so I thought I'd give it a shot, but if it's better asked in another forum, please let me know.

I have written a 2D ray tracer to simulate tomographic radar signals, with refraction and reflection already being implemented. Now I am trying to implement diffraction effects based on the Uniform Theory of Diffraction. To simplify, I find wedges and spawn diffracted rays from there, aiming to find the one with the shortest length to the receiver. However, I'm struggling to think of a method to decide on how many rays I need to spawn at a wedge.

To explain, let me take a short step back. At initialization, I shoot a bundle of rays within a given opening angle from the transmitter towards the receiver, with some (dielectric, i.e. non-metallic, i.e. partially transparent) objects in between. Rays are instantly moved from their current location to the next intersection with an object, per iteration. If I have enough rays to find all valid paths between transmitter and receiver, increasing the number of rays will increase the absolute amplitude of my signal as more of them reach the receiver, but the relative amplitudes between the different peaks corresponding to the different paths will stay the same. In other words, the correct ratio between these parts of the signal naturally arises from the simulation, and this is where I struggle with implementing diffraction.

As I said, I need to spawn new rays at wedges (which will be cylindrical waves in my case), but how do I decide on how many rays need to be spawned? If I spawn too many, then too many will reach the receiver and dominate the signal; if I spawn too few, none or a negligible few will reach the receiver. What will produce the physically correct results?

Comment: hmm I think you would have better luck using something like modulated cones instead of rays because too many rays will be really slow especially on multiple difractions and with cones you could test intersection for whole area involved with single test per object (and split the cone if needed). However I never done anything like that its just a thought... the closest thing to diffraction I made was this [Algorithm for 2D Raytracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32733650/2521214) see the grating optic simulation.

Comment: So cone would have start/end angle , origin position and some cubics or whatever describing wavelength and intensity as function of angle... If you want just conventional rays the number depends on optimization level of your code and speed of your HW used to compute it vs. time requirement of the result ... On CPU its just few rays however if you use GPU you can afford much more rays see [How to implement 2D raycasting light effect in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708022/2521214) or [GLSL 3D back rayracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre I played with the idea of using cones as well, that's probably an improvement I will address in the future, but I also see a few difficulties (such as tracking optical path lengths). But would cones really solve the issue with diffraction? Say I spawn a cone of diffracted rays at a wedge, would that automatically have the correct intensity if part of it arrives at a receiver (after taking the diffraction coefficient from UTD into account)?

Comment: not my cup of tea but polyniomialy modulated cone will be just approximation .... but I would not worry too much as direct rays are also just an approximation (unless you have "infinite" number of them)